# Appending string causing link to render as plain html

Tags: theming, 8

The following code is returning html in plain text instead of link.for example its printing [Edit slides](/admin/dexp_layerslider/15/editslides) intead of converting in to link.

```
$editslides = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'. $row->id . '/editslides');
      $editslides_link = (Link::fromTextAndUrl('Edit slides', $editslides)->toString());
      $exportslides = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'. $row->id . '/export');
      $exportslides_link =  (Link::fromTextAndUrl('Export slides', $exportslides)->toString());
      $deleteslides = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'. $row->id . '/delete');
      $deleteslides_link =  (Link::fromTextAndUrl('Delete', $deleteslides)->toString());
      $tmp[] =  $editslides_link .' ,' .$exportslides_link .' ,' .$deleteslides_link;
```

Though if i don't append string in `$tmp[]` code render the links. For example

```
  $tmp[] =  $editslides_link;
```

The complete code is as below

```
  public function dexp_layerslider_list() {
    $header = [
      'ID',
      'Name',
      'Action',
    ];
    $results = \Drupal::database->select('dexp_layerslider', 'd')->fields('d', [
      'id',
      'name',
    ])->execute();
    foreach ($results as $row) {
      $url = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'. $row->id . '/edit');
      $row->name = (Link::fromTextAndUrl($row->name, $url)->toString());
      $tmp = (array) $row;
      $editslides = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'. $row->id . '/editslides');
      $editslides_link = (Link::fromTextAndUrl('Edit slides', $editslides)->toString());
      $exportslides = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'. $row->id . '/export');
      $exportslides_link =  (Link::fromTextAndUrl('Export slides', $exportslides)->toString());
      $deleteslides = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'. $row->id . '/delete');
      $deleteslides_link =  (Link::fromTextAndUrl('Delete', $deleteslides)->toString());
      $tmp[] =  $editslides_link .' ,' .$exportslides_link .' ,' .$deleteslides_link;
      $rows[] = $tmp;
    }
    $table = array(
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#rows' => $rows,
      '#attributes' => [],
      '#caption' => '',
      '#colgroups' => [],
      '#sticky' => FALSE,
      '#empty' => t('No slider created yet.'),
       );
     return  $table;
  }
```

[image: screenshot of the table generated]

Comment: Are you sure that `$editslides_link` is a string and not a render element?

Comment: @Neograph734  $editslides_link is string. even i typecast it as string the result remain same. One interesting this if i assign $tmp[] =  $editslides_link .' ,'; code above render link as text but if i assign $tmp[] =  $editslides_link ; the code render the link .

Comment: @clive  any insight

Answer (score 3):

The [toString](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Link.php/function/Link%3A%3AtoString/8.2.x) method of Link returns the HTML string for the link object.

HTML strings in the table render array are wrapped in a **markup** element which escapes many HTML tags for security concerns.

You can, however, pass your own render array in the row as follows:

```
$table['#rows'][0]['item']['data'] = [
  '#type' => 'inline_template',
  '#template' => '{{ link1 }}, {{ link2 }}, {{ link3 }}',
  '#context' => [
    'link1' => $link1->toRenderable(),
    'link2' => $link2->toRenderable(),
    'link3' => $link3->toRenderable(),
  ]
];
```

Comment: the problem is with  $table  array. if i print the $rows it output the links in html markup. $table = array(
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#rows' => $rows,
      '#attributes' => [],
      '#caption' => '',
      '#colgroups' => [],
      '#sticky' => FALSE,
      '#empty' => t('No slider created yet.'),
       );

Comment: The problem is that the table render array wraps your string with a markup element. I'll update my answer with how to fix it ,later.

Comment: in the above solution work but how to integrate it with table.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: the above snippet is one row ,how to  display the header and column of the table. i mean how to render in table format.i do agree i am little unclear in explaining the question.

Comment: The same as you did before. You only need to change the cells that contain the links.

Comment: when i try to run the above code snippet  it works but when i plug the same in table cell  , nothing is printed in the table. for example the following snippet prints what i want`  $tmp =  ['#type' =>'inline_template', '#template' => '{{ link1 |raw }}, {{ link2 | raw}}, {{ link3|raw}}','#context' => [link1' => $editslides_link->getGeneratedLink(),'link2' => $editslides_link->getGeneratedLink(),
  'link3' => $editslides_link->getGeneratedLink(),   ];` if i use it in forloop  $rows[] = array('data' => array($row->name, $tmp )); it doesnt print  any thing in the second cell.

Comment: Each row should contain an associate array of cells (the keys should match the table header keys).

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code , if it helps any one.

`public function dexp_layerslider_list() {
    $header = [
        'ID',
        'Name',
        'Action',
    ] ;
    $results = db_select('{dexp_layerslider}', 'd')->fields('d', [
        'id',
        'name',
    ])->execute();
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $url = Url::fromUserInput("/admin/dexp_layerslider/". $row->id . "/edit");
        $row->name = (Link::fromTextAndUrl($row->name, $url));
        $editslides = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'.$row->id.'/editslides');
        $editslides_link = (Link::fromTextAndUrl('Edit slides', $editslides))->toString();
        $exportslides = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'. $row->id . '/export');
        $exportslides_link =  (Link::fromTextAndUrl('Export slides', $exportslides))->toString();
        $deleteslides = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'. $row->id . '/delete');
        $deleteslides_link =  (Link::fromTextAndUrl('Delete', $deleteslides))->toString();
     $tmp =  [
            '#type' => 'inline_template',
             '#template' => '{{ link1 |raw }}, {{ link2 | raw }}, {{ link3 | raw}}',
                '#context' => [
                         'link1' => $editslides_link->getGeneratedLink(),
                         'link2' => $exportslides_link->getGeneratedLink(),
                            'link3' => $deleteslides_link->getGeneratedLink(),
                            ]
                    ];
        // Row with attributes on the row and some of its cells.
     $rows[] = array(
            'data' => array($row->id,$row->name,$tmp )
                );
        }
     $table = array(
        '#type' => 'table',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#rows' => $rows,
        '#sticky' => FALSE,
        '#empty' => t('No slider created yet.'),
         );
        for($i= 0; $i
            $table['#rows'][$i]['data'][2] = $tmp;
        }
    return $table;
 }`